# Problem with Mutlibranch Pipeline configured by jenkins DSL - repository name adding one unnecessary slash at the beggining

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline

I wanted to configure Multibranch Pipeline Job at Jenkins using `jenkins.yml` file.

Here is fragment of my configuration:

```
multibranchPipelineJob('<jenkins-job-name>') {
        branchSources {
          github {
            (...)
            repository('<user-group/repository>')
          }
        }
(...)
}
```

When I deploy jenkins with configurated job like that, I have github repository URL address filled like that:
`https://github.com//user-group/repository`

After github.com I have double slash and because of that automatic repository scanning is not working, I have something like that in logs:

```
[Fri May 22 13:39:00 UTC 2020] Starting branch indexing...
13:39:00 Connecting to https://api.github.com using <github-username>/******
ERROR: [Fri May 22 13:39:00 UTC 2020] Could not update folder level actions from source <id>
hudson.AbortException: Invalid scan credentials when using <github-username>/****** to connect to /<user-group/repository> on https://api.github.com
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.GitHubSCMSource.retrieveActions(GitHubSCMSource.java:1884)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMSource.fetchActions(SCMSource.java:848)
    at jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject.computeChildren(MultiBranchProject.java:600)
    at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.ComputedFolder.updateChildren(ComputedFolder.java:277)
    at com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.FolderComputation.run(FolderComputation.java:164)
    at jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProject$BranchIndexing.run(MultiBranchProject.java:1034)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:428)
[Fri May 22 13:39:00 UTC 2020] Finished branch indexing. Indexing took 0.14 sec
FATAL: Invalid scan credentials when using <github-username>/****** to connect to /<user-group/repository> on https://api.github.com
Finished: FAILURE
```

Is this bug on Multibrach Pipeline Jobs handling?
Is there any way to workaround it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found my answer. I've used other variables and wrote my repository as:

```
repoOwner('<user-group>')
repository('<repository>')
```

And now it works as expected